# Forcing javascript to fire a change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am updating the value of an HTML element using jQuery and this works perfectly.

```
$('#'+ someID).prop('value', currentPerson["Name"]);
```

However, on this element I have been listening for a change (specifically in an option select box), this works perfectly fine when the value is input manually (it submits a post and appends that result to a div). Please note the document ready is stored in a different file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').on('change', '#approverTbl', function(event){
        //do some stuff here
  });
});
```

I have tried to manually force the change by using a .change(), this does not seem to work. Neither does using a trigger.

```
$('#'+ someID).change();

$('#'+ someID).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some custom event for this:

```
$('body').on('change customChange', '#approverTbl', function(event){
```

and then `trigger`:

```
$('#'+ someID).prop('value', currentPerson["Name"]);
$('#approverTbl').trigger('customChange');
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly!
Unfortunately it does not work though, it doesn't break anything, but it seems to work in exactly the same way as before, only triggering events on a manual change to the option select.

Comment: So if you have `selectbox` control have you try to use `val()` method instead: `$('#'+ someID).val( currentPerson["Name"]);`

Comment: It still has the same effect unfortunately.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesjcohen/HuYYn/1/

Managed to get this working yesterday, so not sure why it isn't working in my other code-base, I will try and figure out

Comment: To further clarify the original question.

The rows of a table in which I am looking for a change in an option select are dynamically generated table rows (that are added by javascript that are added by on page load). Unlike in my JSfiddle.

Comment: I solved this by separating out the post code into it's own function, this is called both by the document change and when the value is manually changed using jquery. It seems to be impossible to enforce a change with the option select inside of a table.